# Sever is not comming up with ubuntu 22.04 liver server image

Tags: boot, 22.04, snap

I am trying to build new ubuntu 22.04.1 liver server image [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qO9J.png) 
The hardware is DELL PowerEdge R540

In the installation screen I chose "try or Install" option
but the server is not comming up with continious jobs running  for more than 30 mins

- A start job is running Wait until snapd is fully seeded
- A start job is running casper-md5check Live ISO checksum

Comment: I'm a desktop user, but your message shows *critical medium error* and provides clues on the problem; ie. your install media is faulty. Did you verify the ISO after download & before writing to your media? Did you write it correctly using an appropriate tool? My guess is the casper-md5check would show problems (*if you check it's output! as you didn't provide it*).

Comment: Yes , I do not see any issue with ISO , I can get a sever up and working  virtual vm with virtual box , but using the same image I cannot build a real server

Comment: Following instruction `$echo "5e38b55d57d94ff029719342357325ed3bda38fa80054f9330dc789cd2d43931 *ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso" | shasum -a 256 --check
ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso: OK
`